# Background image when capturing a video in flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality

Hello I'm new to flutter, I want to create a screen where the user would pick an image and in the application they can press on record and stop record, but the hard thing for me is to add a background image similar to when in zoom meetings we can use, how can I perform this, please help me with a good explanation!

I didn't know how to do it :(

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/add-custom-backgrounds-to-your-live-video-calling-application-using-the-agora-flutter-uikit/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.